# Ubuntu 16.04, Firefox: YouTube works, EarthCam.com doesn't

Tags: firefox, flash, webcam

Ubuntu 16.04, Firefox
Youtube - perfect, everything goes well.
EarthCam.com - doesn't work. It seems like stop downloading page at the moment of start downloading flash. Some other pages with flashes also don't work.

Comment: How about trying `sudo apt install flashplugin-installer` and then visiting the website again?

Answer (score 0):

If Flash doesn't work, simply run this command in Terminal.

`sudo -s`

`Password:`

Type in your password (if prompted).

Then, type in the following command:

`apt-get install flashplugin-installer`

Hopefully you should be able to take it from there!
Enjoy flash!

By the way, this is Flash Player 11.2 - Further versions will not work with Linux.

Comment: Why do you even need `sudo -s`? Just `sudo apt install flashplugin-installer` is sufficient.